# SQL Server 2008 language support/encoding

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-7-x64

as i completed my SQL Server 2008 installation, I have created a new table & inserted new test record 
& executed a query.

as my language is not English & is written from right to left. the result window showed one of the columns, that is text
like this:

```
RecordID    Name    Age CustID

1           ????    29     1

RecordID int(IDENTITY)autoincrement
Name nvarchar(50)
Age int
CustID int
```

I’ll appreciate any help to resolve the issue.

Operating  system WIN 7 x64 which has my language support.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

setting Sql Managment Studio as follows :

this Link to [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174596%28SQL.90%29.aspx), 
 Will Show You The Collation should be used for your localisation E.g **Your** Language,

then Run Managment Studio, expand your DataBase Tree.

Select Your Current Database Instance 
(the name Of Your Database) RightClick and Select `Properties`.

this will open the DataBase Properties Window,

From this Window Select `options` and set it accordingly .
Hope This Will Help You .

don't forget to mark as Right answer if it did work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Coulmns should be nchar or nvarchar to store UNICODE characters.

Database Collation should be utf-8...

When inserting string check the encoding of the client, for example if you are loading values from a query in management studio, you should put a **N** before the quote

```
N'£'
```

Loading the value from a web-app you should check page encoding and request *reader* encoding.... and so on.

Comment: it is actually is `nvarchar (50)` what are you suggesting??